# Java - make one specific colour transparant

Tags: java, swing, colors, jframe, translucency

Is it possible to make one specific color transparant in a JFrame?

I know that it is possible in VB.NET, but I would like to know it whether or not it is possible in Java!

For example:
My JFrame has a red backgroundcolor and I want for only that red color to become transparent, so that where that red *was*, I see the behind laying form/desktop.

Hope someone can help, because I'm stuck!

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities.setWindowShape(Window, Shape)
```

with a custom Shape implementation that contains only [points whose color is different from your specific color](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html#per-pixel).

Comment: don't forget to mark this answer as answered when it helped you :)